# Is it a good idea to pack all pages into JSON arrays besides index?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This question is a bit of an odd one, but simply refers to a **Single Page Application** POV - Where one page is loaded then other pages are loaded from *click events*, *refreshing*, and other *events* as such.

And recently I got the idea to simply pack all pages besides `/` (root directory) as JSON, so when pulling data from another page it can be decoded in JSON using `JSON.parse(page)` (JS) then put onto the page, and if there's any problem simply send a 404 message back as an example.

This was a new idea I got while building my SPA, and was curious as to if it was worth all the effort to setting up and managing.

---

#### Example from `localhost/home`

```
{
  "html" : "<h1>This is the home page</h1>"
}
```

#### Example from `localhost/`

```
// add libraries like jQuery, js files
// use php to load the content div that the new data will be placed
// add stylesheets
// etc...
```

---

Which would be retrieved from JS using a `GET` request, then parsed, look in the JSON array for `html` then place it in the correct content box.

Comment: I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel. Why not try something like AngularJS or similar?

Comment: @Z-Bone would this be classed as re-inventing the wheel? I'm currently working on a MVC framework meant to help doing SPAs, and this was just an idea I came up with. :) (`PHP related MVC`)

Comment: Your approach will work.. I'm just saying that Google has done a great job in creating AngularJS for easily creating SPAs :). Once you'll advance in your project and need to do more complex tasks with your app, you'll be glad you used an already existing SPA framework. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks, friend @Z-bone, I understand that Google has the mighty Angular for SPAs, and I just thought it'd be a fun project to learn more about them, and how to write secure and clean code; but I appreciate your POV :')